# How to save the sorting result to model

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable, save

I create a JTable in one frame. It shows the data from MyModel.
Now when I click the header of column, it will do sorting.
It works fine.

But when I close this frame, and open it again.
The data in this table is shown as the original order in MyModel.

Now I want to save the sorting result when I close the frame.
Should I update the MyModel with the new order data 
or save sorting on which column and which order (ASCENDING or DESCENDING).

How to implement this? Thanks!

Comment: Consider posting [a **Minimal**, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for faster help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this - 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting

The main idea is that you need an object - TableRowSorter which will keep information about your sorting.

Comment: +1 Or maybe just use the getSortKeys() method of the DefaultRowSorter to get the List containing the sorting information. Then you can serialize/deserialize this List and use the setSortKeys(...) method then next time the program is started.